# To prevent overflow of text from the corner in tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I get sometimes overflow from the right-hand-side corner like this

[image]

for this minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}


\begin{document}
\begin{question}
...
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

**How can you prevent the overflow without making the width of the box any wider in the tikz environment?**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with your MWE. If I type the text from your image into the question environment, I get a bad box warning, which means TeX has exhausted its methods to justify the margins. In this warning, you should also see that 'bundling' does not have any pre-set hyphenation points, which is the root of the issue in this particular case. To resolve the issue, either reword your text or add `\hyphenation{bun-dling}` (a hyphenation point between syllables) in your preamble if this is acceptable to you.

Comment: It seems as hyphenation problem. The code runs well here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the word "bundling" seems to have no hyphenation points. In fact, even loading `babel`, you still have no hyphenation patterns for that word.

The following example shows this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}


\begin{document}
\begin{question}{\bfseries Virulence factor for H.Pylori?}
Adherence proteins, bundling factors of\dots
\end{question}

\textbf{Question 1 Virulence factor for H.Pylori?}
Adherence proteins, bundling factors of\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can notice it even inserting that word in the [online hyphenation tool](http://www.ushuaia.pl/hyphen/?ln=en), which "hyphe­na­tion algo­rithm is based on TeX system".

What you can do is to insert a `\sloppy` command inside the problematic `question` environments, so to make LaTeX less fussy about line breaking.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\mdfdefinestyle{que}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=que]{question}


\begin{document}
\begin{question}{\bfseries Virulence factor for H.Pylori?}
\sloppy
Adherence proteins, bundling factors of\dots
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, if you know that the word "bundling" has some hyphenation points, add them manually with `\-`.

Comment: You can also put `\raggedright`.